# Sum if multiple negative criteria

Tags: excel, ms-office

I know this sounds lame, but I'm struggling with Microsoft Excel to make this formula work.

I need to sum numbers if matches two criterias, one positive and one negative.

The positive critirea is ok, but the negative one must be "if the cell text is not 'ACTIVE'). How to acomplish this?

This is the formula (with both positive criterias) I have so far:

```
=SUMIFS($M$8:$M$100819;$C$8:$C$100819;CONCATENATE(TEXT(D$1;"0");"*");$S$8:$S100819;"ACTIVE")
```

I need to negat that "ACTIVE", and I don't know how and google itself is not helping very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use :

```
<SUM_OF_ALL_ITEMS_WITH_FIRST_CRITERIA> - SUMIFS($M$8:$M$100819;$C$8:$C$100819;CONCATENATE(TEXT(D$1;"0");"*");$S$8:$S100819;"ACTIVE")
```

Answer (score 4):

Another soultion would be to add `<>` to the criteria, as in:

```
=SUMIFS($M$8:$M$100819;$C$8:$C$100819;CONCATENATE(TEXT(D$1;"0");"*");$S$8:$S100819;"<>ACTIVE")
```